# How to parse HTML node in R

Tags: html, r, parsing

I've coded in R before but never have done anything with HTML so bear with me.

I set up a script to pull in some useful information about a school and here's the gist of it:

```
source <- html(url)
address_phone_information <- html_node(source, css = "h4")
```

If I run `address_phone_information` I get

```
<h4>
                801 East Arctic Street, Palmer, AK 99645-6179            |
        907-746-2358              
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.acc.matsuk12.us/">WEBSITE</a>                 </h4>
```

Ideally, I'd like to only pull out the address information (`801 East Arctic Street, Palmer, AK 99645-6179`) as well as the telephone number (`907-746-2358`) and store those in two different variables `address` and `phone`.

The even better solution would be to store the different pieces of the address in four variables, `street`, `city`, `state`, and `zip` but that doesn't seem very hard to do once I have the address squared away.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this? I have other schools to look at too and would like to use the exact same code. Also, I can provide the url if that would help.

Comment: look at package `rvest`. It has function  like `html_text` to get inside a node once you have located the node with `html_node` and options for trimming whitespace. It appears that a pipe character (|) separates the address and phone so `str_split` from package `stringr` may help.

If the address formatting is very consistent  then `str_extract` from package stringr with some careful regexes should get you the parts of he addresses

Comment: That helped me a lot. I was able to parse out all of the address information with `str_split` and `str_trim` helped me eliminate all of the white space.